# $(hostname) doesn't work in cronjob

Tags: cron, hostname

I have a simple backup script with this line to come up with a name for the backup:

```
backup=$(/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M_%S')_$(hostname).gz
```

It works great when I run it under the root user.  Unfortunately when I set it to run as a cronjob, the $(hostname) part is always empty and I don't get the hostname.  Why isn't it working, and how can I get the hostname in a cron job?

I'm running ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Since you specify `/bin/date` with an explicit path: Is `PATH` set correctly to contain `hostname`?

Comment: Is that a line from the actual cron schedule? `%` is special in crontabs, and must be escaped. See e.g. [How can I execute \`date\` inside of a cron tab job?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/29578)

Comment: @DonHolgo You are exactly right!  I don't know why I didn't think of that! Works perfect once I add the full path.

Comment: @user3413723 Ok, I've turned that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hostname` doesn't seem to be in the `PATH` in your script. Either put `/bin/hostname` there, like you did for `date`, or set `PATH` to include `/bin` (inside the script or in the crontab).

Comment: It would be better to investigate why the root user's PATH is wrong, which indicates a deeper issue with the system.

Answer (score 2):

Crontab has its own variables lists for path etc...you might use them or run from crontab a bash script instead of a shell-like commad.

This is how to use crontab

```
VARIABLE=value
PATH=/bin:/path/to/doanything
0 0 * * * doanything.sh $VARIABLE
```